# How do I access jQuery from a new window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

In my app I open a new window with `var w = window.open()`. I access the CanvasJS API with:

```
var canvas = w.document.createElement('script');

canvas.type = "text/javascript";
canvas.src = "https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js";

w.document.head.appendChild(canvas);
```

This works perfectly fine. I did the same thing with jQuery and made sure to append it before my own script yet I get this error: `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Here is what my code looks like:

```
var w = window.open('','_blank',width,height);

w.document.body.innerHTML = '<body> //create chart container here </body>';

var jQuery = w.document.createElement('script');
var canvas = w.document.createElement('script');
var script = w.document.createElement('script');

canvas.type = "text/javascript";
canvas.src = "https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js";

jQuery.type = "text/javascript";
jQuery.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js";

script.textContent = "//my script content here, this is where I use the '$' jQuery object";

w.document.head.appendChild(jQuery);
w.document.head.appendChild(canvas);
w.document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Dynamically added scripts are loaded asynchronously, and the order of the finished loadings varies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you have inserted the script tag in the head but this does not mean that the script have been downloaded completely. You code runs before the browser is able to download jQuery. Dynamically inserted script tags perform async operation.

I suggest that you setup an interval and check if jQuery is available. Once it is available execute your code. Name the script element created for jQuery something else as it will interfere with checking for jquery within your interval.

```
var jqueryCheck = setInterval(function() {
    if(window.jQuery) {
        clearInterval(jqueryCheck); 
         // execute your code
    }
 }, 100);
```

Comment: This was it! Thank you, I'll mark your answer when I can.